# Anything wrong with this simpler bind for Cont?

Tags: haskell, continuations

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

newtype C a = C {runCont :: forall r. (a -> r) -> r} 

instance Functor C where  
  fmap f (C arr) = C $ \br -> arr $ br . f

instance Applicative C where
  pure a = C ($ a)
  (C abrr) <*> (C arr) = C $ \brr -> abrr ( \ab -> arr ( brr . ab ) )

instance Monad C where 
  -- (C arr) >>= aCbrr = C $ \br -> arr (\a -> runCont (aCbrr a) br) -- The usual
  (C arr) >>= aCbrr = arr aCbrr -- My simpler idea with the same result in this test

main :: IO ()
main = print $ flip runCont id $ do
  x <- pure (5::Int)
  y <- pure $ 2 * x
  z <- pure $ take y $ repeat 'a'
  pure z
```

Upon Noughtmare's suggestion adding some law proofs. I think they make sense intuitively but the commented steps might not be formally sound:

```
Left identity: pure a >>= h === h a

pure a >>= h
C (\k -> k a) >>= h
(\k -> k a) h
h a

Right identity: m >>= pure === m

m >>= pure
C arr >>= pure
arr pure
arr ( \a -> C (\k -> k a) )
C ( \k -> k (arr id) ) -- because arr knows nothing about r
C arr -- because arr::(a->r)->r so k::a->r
m

Associativity: 

(m >>= f) >>= g         ===    m >>= (\x -> f x >>= g)
((C arr) >>= f) >>= g   ===    (C arr) >>= (\x -> f x >>= g)
(arr f) >>= g          
f (arr id) >>= g
(pure.h) (arr id) >>= g ===    (C arr) >>= (\x -> (pure.h) x >>= g)
C (h (arr id)) >>= g    ===    arr ( \x -> (C (h x)) >>= g )
                        ===    C (h (arr id)) >>= g
```

Comment: Have you tried proving the monad laws? Where do you get stuck? If you don't know how to do that, check out [Haskell Unfolder 8: Laws](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V7673JaWXaA&list=PLD8gywOEY4HaG5VSrKVnHxCptlJv2GAn7&index=9).

Comment: Left identity is easy. Working on the others

Comment: Hm. Possibly stupid question: can you still define `callCC` if you quantify away the return type like this? If not, that seems like a pretty strong drawback of this bind definition, as it looks to me like it relies critically on the quantification.

Comment: You can derive Monad and all that via [`Codensity Identity`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/kan-extensions-5.2.5/docs/Control-Monad-Codensity.html) because `C` as a CPS encoding of Identity has the same in-memory representation as `Codensity Identity`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your modified definition works fine (except I don't know how you got `flip runCont` to type check -- I think you need to flip the arguments manually).  However, I also think you'll find that your continuation monad isn't very useful.

The usual continuation monad is a rank-1 type:

```
newtype C' r a = C' { runCont' :: (a -> r) -> r }
```

and it's useful because a `C' r a` is "almost isomorphic" to an `a` value, except that the type `r` is known.  This means that you can construct a monadic value of type `C' Int Char` representing a pure `Char`:

```
C' (\f -> f 'A')   -- same as `pure 'A'`
```

but you can *also* construct a monadic value of the same type `C' Int Char` that short circuits the computation with an `Int` return value:

```
C' (\f -> 42)
```

In constrast, your rank-2 continuation monad:

```
newtype C a = C { runCont :: forall r. (a -> r) -> r }
```

is *precisely* isomorphic to type `a`.  One direction of the isomorphism is given by `pure`, and the other is given by:

```
unpure :: C a -> a
unpure (C f) = f id
```

So, with your `C Char`, you can represent a pure `Char`:

```
C (\f -> f 'A')    -- equivalent to `pure 'A'`
```

and that's it.

Because of this isomorphism, your `arr` is always equal to the section `($ a0)` for some `a0 :: a`, and your `aCbrr` is always equal to `\a' -> C ($ f a')` for some `f :: a -> b`, and this means that the original definition of `>>=` gives:

```
(C arr) >>= aCbrr 
-- by original definition of `>>=`
= C $ \br -> arr (\a -> runCont (aCbrr a) br)
-- by the above equivalencies
= C $ \br -> ($ a0) (\a -> runCont ((\a' -> C ($ f a')) a) br)
-- and simplify
= C $ \br -> ($ a0) (\a -> runCont (C ($ f a)) br)
= C $ \br -> (\a -> runCont (C ($ f a)) br) a0
= C $ \br -> runCont (C ($ f a0)) br
= C $ \br -> ($ f a0) br
= C ($ f a0)
```

while your modified definition of `>>=` gives

```
(C arr) >>= aCbrr
-- by your definition of `>>=`
= arr aCbrr
-- by the above equivalencies
= ($ a0) (\a' -> C ($ f a'))
-- and simplify
= (\a' -> C ($ f a')) a0
= C ($ f a0)
```

so the two definitions are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried changing to the usual `newtype C r a = C {runCont :: (a -> r) -> r}` and then my `>>=` doesn't compile cos it's trying to unify `r` with `C r b`.